# imports and constants marked as unused, while they are used?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a little rust crate that I have made, and I now just made a test file for it.

I have these files in src:

```
.
├── as.rs
├── dhr.rs
├── ed.rs
├── encryption.rs
├── kdf.rs
├── lib.rs
├── phypayload.rs
└── tests.rs
```

and my `lib.rs` that looks like this:

#![no_std]

```
extern crate alloc;

pub mod ed;
pub mod r#as;
pub mod tests;
pub mod kdf;
pub mod encryption;
pub mod dhr;
pub mod phypayload;
```

And my `tests.rs` file looks like this:

```
#[cfg(test)]
use super::r#as::ASRatchet;
use super::ed::EDRatchet;
use rand_core::OsRng;

mod tests {

    
use super::*;


pub const  SK : [u8;32] = [
    16, 8, 7, 78, 159, 104, 210, 58, 89, 216, 177, 79, 10, 252, 39, 141, 8, 160, 148, 36, 29,
    68, 31, 49, 89, 67, 233, 53, 16, 210, 28, 207,
];
pub const DOWNLINK : [u8;32] = [
    0, 171, 247, 26, 19, 92, 119, 193, 156, 216, 49, 89, 90, 174, 165, 23, 124, 247, 30, 79,
    73, 164, 55, 63, 178, 39, 228, 26, 180, 224, 173, 104,
];
pub const UPLINK : [u8;32] = [
    218, 132, 151, 66, 151, 72, 196, 104, 152, 13, 117, 94, 224, 7, 231, 216, 62, 155, 135, 52,
    59, 100, 217, 236, 115, 100, 161, 95, 8, 146, 123, 146,
];

pub const DEVADDR : [u8;4] = [1, 2, 3, 2];
#[test]

fn correctness() {
    let mut ed_ratchet = EDRatchet::new(SK,UPLINK,DOWNLINK, DEVADDR, OsRng);
    let mut as_ratchet = ASRatchet::new(SK, DOWNLINK, UPLINK, DEVADDR, OsRng);

    let ciphertext = ed_ratchet.ratchet_encrypt_payload(b"Message");

    let decrypedmessage = as_ratchet.receive(ciphertext).unwrap().0;
    assert_eq!(decrypedmessage,b"Message");

    let ciphertext2 = as_ratchet.ratchet_encrypt_payload(b"Message");


    let decrypedmessage2 = ed_ratchet.receive(ciphertext2).unwrap().unwrap();



    assert_eq!(decrypedmessage2,b"Message");
}
```

So I'm using vs code, and currently, all the three const test lists are underlined with a yellow squiggly line, implying that they are unused, the same goes for the import `use super::*;` . And I also get a warning about it when I compile.

This is weird, since I am using the lists, and the import.

I also tried moving the top imports into to the `tests` module, like this:

```
mod tests {
use super::r#as::ASRatchet;
use super::ed::EDRatchet;
use rand_core::OsRng;

    
use super::*;
```

But when I do this, I get the following:

```
unresolved import `super::ed`

could not find `ed` in `super`rustc(E0432)
```

How do I remove the "unused" warnings for things that are not unused?
And also why can't I move my imports into the module?

Comment: I suggest you read the [chapter on tests from The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html#integration-tests). Essentially, create a top-level directory called `tests`, put your test files in there.

Comment: you have a `crate::tests::tests` module which may not be what you want; it is already in module `tests` because of the file structure, you don't also need the `mod tests {}`. With the file module, you also probably want `#![cfg(test)]` (with a `!`) to mark the whole file, as opposed to marking the `use`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to explain the issue, here is your module hierarchy:

- crate (`lib.rs`)

  - `ed` (`ed.rs`)
  - `as` (`as.rs`)
  - `kdf` (`kdf.rs`)
  - `encryption` (`encryption.rs`)
  - `dhr` (`dhr.rs`)
  - `phypayload` (`phypayload.rs`)
  - `tests` (`tests.rs`)

    - `tests` (inline module within `tests.rs`)

When you originally had the following:

```rust
use super::r#as::ASRatchet;
use super::ed::EDRatchet;
use rand_core::OsRng;

mod tests {
    use super::*;
```

That was importing `ASRatchet`, `EDRatchet`, and `OsRng` into the upper `tests` module. Items aren't inherited into sub-modules, so the `use super::*` imports everything from the parent `tests` module into the child inline `tests` module.

`super::` only goes up one module, so when you attempted to move them into the child module, the paths are now looking for those in the parent `tests` module. Of course they won't work there.

In order to move those `use` statements into the child `tests` module, you have two options. I'd recommend you use the `crate::` syntax:

```rust
mod tests {
    use crate::r#as::ASRatchet;
    use crate::ed::EDRatchet;
    use rand_core::OsRng;
```

which tells the compiler to start from the top level of your crate, which will work from any context.

Another option is to use `super::super::`, but that's ugly and brittle. I generally prefer to use `crate::` whever possible, and only use `super::` in unit tests, where importing everything from the parent module is useful.

---

Now that your immediate question is answered, let me explain a few more things.

`#[cfg(test)]` (and in general, all `#[cfg(..)]`s) only applies to one item. You should apply it to every item that will be used only when running tests. With the imports inside the `tests` module, apply it like so:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
```

You have a `tests` module within a `tests`  module. I'd recommend removing the inner one, and moving the `#[cfg(test)]` to `lib.rs` like so:

```rust
// lib.rs
extern crate alloc;

pub mod ed;
pub mod r#as;
pub mod kdf;
pub mod encryption;
pub mod dhr;
pub mod phypayload;

#[cfg(test)]
pub mod tests;
```

```rust
// tests.rs
use crate::r#as::ASRatchet;
use crate::ed::EDRatchet;
use rand_core::OsRng;

pub const  SK : [u8;32] = [
    16, 8, 7, 78, 159, 104, 210, 58, 89, 216, 177, 79, 10, 252, 39, 141, 8, 160, 148, 36, 29,
    68, 31, 49, 89, 67, 233, 53, 16, 210, 28, 207,
];

...etc
```

But if this is meant for integration tests using only publicly available items, I'd recommend using the [`tests` directory](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-03-test-organization.html#integration-tests).